The key field 'Id' must be of type Edm.String in Azure Search with EF Core
I have EF Core implemented in my project. I was trying to generate the Azure Index and Azure Indexer for AI Search.
However, when I try to create using C# code. It throws an error.

{ "error": { "code": "InvalidRequestParameter", "message": "The request is invalid. Details: definition : The key field 'Id' must be of type Edm.String.", "details":[ { "code": "InvalidKeyField", "message": "The key field 'Id' must be of type Edm.String. Parameters: definition" } ] } }

How can any fix it so that I don't need to change datatypes of my primary key in EF Core models?

If you donot want to change the type then while sending data to aure search use :
return entities.Select(rith => new RithSEarchEnt     {         Id = rith.Id.ToString(),       });
